# Causing function to run from emit between SFCs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to make a subheader slide up or down, depending on its current state when I click a div on my header using emit. My header and subheader are in separate files, so I'm trying to slide it up or down using a div in the parent. I am new to Vue and web-frameworks overall. I picked through vue docs and other examples with no avail.

Parent code (App.vue):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router';
import Header from './components/Header.vue';
import TopicBar from './components/Topicbar.vue';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Child from './components/Header.vue';

const subheaderstate = ref(false);

function subslide(){
  subheaderstate.value = !subheaderstate.value;
  if(subheaderstate.value){
    $('#topicbar').SlideUp();
  }
  else{
    $('#topicbar').SlideDown();
  }
}
</script>



<template>
  <header>
      <Header/>
  </header>
  <div id="topicbar">
    <TopicBar @toggle-subheader="subslide"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Child code (Header.vue):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, provide, ref, inject } from 'vue';
import $ from 'jquery';


function flip(){
    const $arrow = $("#header_arrow");
    const isFlipped = $arrow.hasClass("flipp");

    if(isFlipped) {
        $arrow.removeClass("flipp");
        $arrow.css({"transform":"rotate(0deg)", "transition-duration":"1s"});
    } else{
        $arrow.addClass("flipp");
        $arrow.css({"transform":"rotate(180deg)", "transition-duration":"1s"});
    }
}
</script>
<script lang="ts">

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'Child',
    methods:
    {
        sub(){
            this.$emit('toggleSubheader')
        }
    }
});
</script>


<template>
    <h1 id="header_icon">Limits</h1>
    <input type="text" id="header_search" placeholder="Search posts and communities..."/>
    <div id="header_contact">Contact</div>
    <div id="header_topics" @click="flip(); sub();">Topics<img id="header_arrow" class="arrow flipp" src="./assets/down.svg" alt="down"></div>
    <div id="header_about">About Us</div>
    <div id="header_login">Login</div>
    <div id="header_signup">Sign Up</div>
</template>
```

The function set up to hide or show the subheader isn't even running, even though I am using emit and importing the correct component.

Comment: It's unclear if these are typos or code is really that troublesome. TopicBar is not shown, it's unclear how it's related to toggle-subheader event. Header is called Child, so <Header/> is not a component, just html element. <Header> doesn't have toggle-subheader listener, so you can't expect emit('toggleSubheader') to affect anything. Generally you shouldn't mix jQuery with Vue, this makes everything flaky and usually indicates that it was hard for a dev to make it work the proper way.

Comment: The topic bar code is irrelevant, as the div in the parent encompasses the entirety of the topicbar component. Really good observation on the “hard for a dev to make it work the proper way”, I wonder how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: Then It's <Header> (or more correctly, <Child>) that needs  `@toggle-subheader="subslide"`, not `<TopicBar>`. It's personal experience. The devs stick the way they can make it work, which is jQuery when one transits from jQuery to modern framework. These things are orthogonal and don't work well together. Direct DOM access without a valid reason is discouraged in proper Vue code, this can lead to several kinds of design and behavior problems that wouldn't happen otherwise. It's not the case here but can become the next problem to solve, depending on how jQuery slide plugin works